# jQuery Lightbox For Native Galleries wordpress plugin buttons not showing outside box

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

Hi I am Using the jQuery Lightbox For Native Galleries for Wordpress which uses the colorbox plugin.

I am trying to position the Prev, Next and Close buttons on the edge of the lightbox but the buttons keep on cropping. Have tried playing around with the z-index of the elements and nothing is working.

I am pulling my hair out as I feel like I have hit a wall, hence if anyone can help me get through it that would be fantastic.

Hope someone can help.

Here is the URL

http://satbulsara.com/luke-irwin/?page_id=14

Comment: nice site. the problem is that the borders are on the same level als de image container, while the buttons are inside the container. So simply changing your z-index to a billion won't make a difference since it's level can't be higher than it's parent. You could maybe fix this whit position relative though. i'll try figure it out in a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
#cboxContent { overflow: visible; }
```

Tried it in firebug. #cboxContent is the container of the buttons. It has the property of `overflow: hidden`. That's why your buttons are cropped at the edges.

Comment: been trying to figure this otu pulling my hair out